# DataSet not updating Database

Tags: c#, dataset, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I have a dataset with about 6 rows. I can confirm the dataset's table is filled by getting its row count.
I fill the dataset with rows from a previously filled dataset from a different source. According to all the articles I've found here and on the internet in general, I'm supposed to call `dataset.datatable.AcceptChanges()` then `tableadapter.Update(dataset.datatable)`, but the new data is never recorded on the new database. This is what I'm doing:

```
using FbConnection originalDB = new FbConnection($@"data source=localhost;initial catalog={AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}OLD_DATABASE.FDB;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey");
using FbConnection destinationDB = new FbConnection($@"data source=localhost;initial catalog={AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}NEW_DATABASE.FDB;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey");

var originalset = new DataSet1();
var destinationset = new DataSet1();

var groupsTableAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.GroupsTableAdapter() { Connection = originalDB };

groupsTableAdapter .Fill(originalset.GroupsTable);

groupsTableAdapter= new DataSet1TableAdapters.GroupsTableAdapter() { Connection = destinationDB };

foreach (DataSet1.GroupsRow groupRow in originalset.GroupsTable.Rows)
{ 
            destinationset.GroupsTable.ImportRow(groupRow);
            Console.WriteLine($"ROW PROCESSED> {groupRow.GroupID}");
}
int rows = destinationset.GroupsTable.Rows.Count;
Console.WriteLine(rows + " added");
destinationset.GroupTable.AcceptChanges();
GroupsTableAdapter.Update(destinationset.GroupsTable);
```

When I check the database with a third-party software, the table is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where did you get that idea about `AcceptChanges`?  The documentation says the opposite: `The DataRowState also changes: all Added and Modified rows become Unchanged, and Deleted rows are removed.` - any changes queued for the db are cancelled!. You want the opposite: set `da.AcceptChangesDuringFill` to false on your dataadapter so that all rows loaded from the source are treated as new.

Comment: use http://fbprofiler.sf.net to see which requests are actually delivered to your database. The usual reason is that your applicaiton did not commit database transaction.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I read it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055799/how-to-save-the-dataset-after-making-changes-to-the-database and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824967/datatable-importrow-is-not-adding-rows

Comment: (Un)fortunately, we finally ditched the third-party database, and are now using our own.